# How do I send data in JavaScript onclick call and then access it in the click handler function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This has had me stuck for a while. My web searches regarding the `onclick` JavaScript call has it sometimes with a capital C as in `onClick` and other times `onclick`. My code is part of a JQuery Mobile app but the `onclick` is JS. So, it looks like this:

```
domEntry = '<li><a href="#poet-details"';
domEntry += ' onclick="getPoetDetails('+ poet_name + ')">';
domEntry += poet_name;
domEntry += '</a></li>';
```

I'm going to add that to a div. `'poet_name` does display correctly with the 3rd line. How do I access it in `getPoetDetails`? Did I call it right?
Also, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/brucewhealton/XF5AJ/

The function `getPoetDetails` can be seen at the link given. Do I access it through an event object variable? The application sends a query string to another location, dbpedia.org/sparql, and gets back JSON. I need the poet_selected or poet_name for the second query to get details about the poet because my app is so far only listing poets, not very interesting. I want to figure this out so that I can start my app by letting the user select the nationality from among a category of "Poets_by_nationality" on DBpedia.org. My problem is capturing the user's selection, what they click on or tap on in a jQuery Mobile app and sending it to another function.

Comment: can you not use jQuery to handle the click event? If you are using jQuery, you should probably just stick with that rather than mixing styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are having trouble with an onClick for your anchor tags of poet names? What I think to be the best way to do this is to not have any inline javascript. With this, when you are starting your javascript in the window ready or however you chose to do it, you should add this little line

```
$('#result').delegate('a', 'click', getPoetDetails);
```

This tells jQuery to look inside of #result and whenever there is a new anchor tag apply this click event to it. The click event should call getPoetDetails.

Now where you are creating and inserting your anchor tags you should get rid of the javascript stuff and instead have this

```
domEntry = '<li><a href="#poet-details"';
domEntry += 'data-name="'+ poet_name + '">';
domEntry += poet_name;
domEntry += '</a></li>';
```

This is giving the anchor a data value of name with the value of the poet's name. Now you can use jQuery to get this data inside your getPoetDetails function. The start of it can now be this, and keep the rest the same.

```
var getPoetDetails = function(){
var poet_name_selected = $(this).data('name');
// show loader
```

I'm pretty sure you are either doing something wrong when you are calling to get your json data, or you are parsing it wrong, but now at least the name is got correctly by getPoetDetails. In order for this to be shown as working in jsfiddle you need to change the onLoad drop down to noWrap body since you already have the document ready in your js.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `poet_name` is a string, then it should be wrapped in quotes:

```
domEntry += ' onclick="getPoetDetails(\''+ poet_name + '\')">';
```

So the resulting HTML will look like:

```
onclick="getPoetDetails('Henry Abbey')"
```

Also, you will need to choose 'no wrap' rather than 'onLoad' from the jsfiddle settings to make the function `getPoetDetails` global.

Edit: Here's another way to do it:

```
domEntry = '<li><a href="#poet-details" class="poet">';
domEntry += poet_name;
domEntry += '</a></li>';
```

Then just after the loop:

```
$('.poet').click(function() {
    getPoetDetails($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks... that didn't fix it.  I wonder if I can update poet_selected as a global variable?  Would that be a way to do it?  I don't see that poet_name or poet_selected will ever be used in more than one place.  That might help with debugging because if I set it initially to something then I'll be able to see if the other function works.
Bruce

Comment: Global variables are actually considered to be quite bad. I've updated my answer with another way of doing it.

Comment: It seems to work other than one thing, I am having trouble specifying a JSON result variable that might exist or might not exist.  When the query is sent to DBpedia.org it asks for an optional result variable.  Specifically, if I want to display the writing that the poet was known for, that may be returned or it may not be returned.  Ok, so I am trying to check for poet_results.creative_work_name.value;  JS doesn't like this: if (typeof poet_results.creative_work_name.value != "undefined")  I've tried to first set that to another variable but it is still a problem.

Comment: Just see if it `=== undefined`, and only display it if it isn't undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in the getPoetDetails(poet_name_selected) function that is declared, the poet_name_selected will be poet_name.

Comment: Yes, that is right.  I tried to paste it into this comment area but I am unable to make code show up in the comment.  It is here: http://jsfiddle.net/brucewhealton/tQnNT/ toward the bottom.  The first call to a similar query works, it is called getPoets but I'm not passing data into the function from an item clicked on.